# Slide new activity from bottom with navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I would like to implement something similar like can be seen here. Basicaly, one can slide up new activity from the bottom.

[image: first]
[image: second]

My activity has navigation drawer inside.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >

    <!-- Framelayout pre zobrazovanie jednotlivých fragmentov -->
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview ako menu pre navDrawer -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#2B2B2B"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Is there any way how can I achive this ?

Comment: you can use custom view at bottom, animate it and make visibility visible or gone according to the situation.

Comment: @Naser more words about this ? some codes to look into ?

Comment: you can get some idea from this question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597890/not-getting-relativelayouts-getheight-after-setting-visibility-visible-from-v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to the original question of sliding an activity from bottom of the screen, use the following code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(FirstActivity.this,R.anim.slide_in_up,0);
startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

slide_in_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

You could define your own exit animation in the third parameter of the function `makeCustomAnimation`

As for the specific response as per your screens, @Naser 's reply seems like the way to go