# View in Fragment's layout not being inflated at the right time?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

I am trying to find out the height of a certain layout in my fragment's layout as soon as it is created because I want to use it in an animation to make it pop up on click events. These are the two animations:

```
private void hideEditSetFragment() {
    TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(
            0,                 // fromXDelta
            0,                 // toXDelta
            0,  // fromYDelta
            mEditSetContainer.getHeight());                // toYDelta
    animate.setDuration(500);
   // animate.setFillAfter(true);

    TranslateAnimation animate1 = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,mBottomNavigationView.getHeight(),0);
    animate1.setDuration(500);
   // animate1.setFillAfter(true);
    mBottomNavigationView.startAnimation(animate1);
    mEditSetContainer.startAnimation(animate);
    mBottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mEditSetContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

private void showEditSetFragment() {
    mEditSetContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Log.i(TAG, "showEditSetFragment(): mEditSetContainer height is " + mEditSetContainer.getMeasuredHeight());
    TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(
            0,                 // fromXDelta
            0,                 // toXDelta
            mEditSetContainer.getHeight(),  // fromYDelta
            0);                // toYDelta
    animate.setDuration(1000);
    //animate.setFillAfter(true);

    TranslateAnimation animate1 = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,mBottomNavigationView.getHeight());
    animate1.setDuration(1000);
    //animate1.setFillAfter(true);
    mBottomNavigationView.startAnimation(animate1);
    mEditSetContainer.startAnimation(animate);
    mBottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mEditSetContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

The problem is that my `mEditSetContainer` needs to be drawn at least once to be able to be used in this animation as I use its height. So, during `onCreateView()`, I set it to visible:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle onSavedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView()");
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_current_workout, container, false);


    v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_current_workout_recycler_view);
    mPerformedExercisesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mEditSetContainer = (ConstraintLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_current_workout_edit_set_container);
    mEditSetFragment = new EditSetFragment();
    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_current_workout_edit_set_container, mEditSetFragment, "EditSetFragment").commit();
    mEditSetContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mEditSetContainer.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "Runnable called " + String.valueOf( mEditSetContainer.getHeight()));
            Log.i(TAG, "Runnable called " + String.valueOf( mBottomNavigationView.getHeight()));
            mEditSetContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

I used a runnable here as it is supposed to be called after being draw according to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/views-getwidth-and-getheight-returns-0). However, the view is still not drawn for the `mEditSetContainer` when the view for the `mBottomNavigationView` is. It is to note that the `mEditSetContainer` has its height defined by wrap-content and that it is a container for a nested fragment. My question is how can I get its height when the fragment is created? I need to know this to be able to run my animation. What currently happens is that on the first click, the animation is skipped but it works after. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597890/not-getting-relativelayouts-getheight-after-setting-visibility-visible-from-v) is also a related thread that could help, but hasn't.

Also, please do not suggest setting my views to invisible. I need to have them set to gone as they are not supposed to take room when not in use. The `mEditSetFragment` overlaps other content when shown.

Comment: Why can't you get the height at the time of animation? Why get it when the fragment is created?

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal This would work on the second time the animation starts, but no the first. I call the animation on onResume() and the view is not yet finished sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in `onCreateView`:

```
mEditSetContainer.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        height = mEditSetContainer.getHeight();
        //Other operations
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you man, this is the right answer. I actually set the visibility to visible in onCreateView() and then in onGlobalLayout() I set it to GONE, which allowed the view to be drawn and measured for my animation's use.